# How do I caclulate the probability of hash collisions?

Tags: probability, applications

I have a 10Gb file and the entire file is overwritten with random data every day.

Afterwards, I divide the data into blocks and hash each block to generate a fingerprint.

I am trying to choose an appropriate<sup>1</sup> hash size to make it unlikely that that will be a collision (a false match in the hash for a particular block as compared to the previous iteration: a match is OK if the data is randomly *the same* but not if it's showing the same hash for different data).

How can I calculate the probability of a false match in 10 years given the block size and hash length?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> appropriate means: as small as possible without making the first collision more than 50% likely in 10 years</sub>

Comment: Do you only count collisions against the latest previous block, or against all previous blocks? And only against the block at the same position? And how many blocks are there?

Comment: We only count against the latest previous block and only against the block in the same position. The number of blocks depend on the block size chosen, the whole file is 10Gb. Block sizes under consideration are: 1k,4k,16k,64k

Comment: In that case the probability of a false match is simply 2^n per block per day for an n bit hash. But unless you really care about space, I'd go with something conservative, like 128 bits.

Comment: So for 10 years the probability of not having a collision would be: `(2-(2^n-1)/2^n)^(10*365*10G/b)-1` where 'b' is the block size in bytes?

Comment: (we do really care about space)

Comment: Your chance of a collision on each day is based on the amount of the address space you have consumed.  Thus on the first day, it is 1/2^n (where n is the bits).  Each additional hash, the numerator goes up by 1 as the address space is filled.  You then want the odds that none of those picks are a duplicate, but my probability math is failing me for the moment on what that looks like simplified down.  Also, hi.

Comment: Also, while it may be a security related implication, they may have a better answer on Math since it's really a probability question only tangentially related to security.

Comment: @AJHenderson Hi! and thanks I'll flag for migration there :)

Comment: @AJHenderson That quadratic scaling doesn't apply since the OP only cares about matches with the single previous block, not all of them. No filling up of address space here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the hash function behaves like a [random oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle), then the probability that any given block hashes to the same value as the previous version of the same block is *2<sup>-n</sup>*, for a hash function output size of *n* bits. If you have *k* blocks in your file, then, over ten years, you are computing *k·3653* block hashes (or *k·3652* or *k·3654*, depending on leap years), so the probability of not hitting a collision in 10 years will be equal to *(1-2<sup>-n</sup>)<sup>k·3653</sup>*. It is simpler to count the average time between two occurrences of a collision: it will be *2<sup>n</sup>/k* days.

For instance, if using 1 kB blocks in a 10 GB file, then *k = 10<sup>7</sup>* (ten million blocks). If *n = 128*, then the average time between two collisions will be close to *10<sup>40</sup>* years, i.e. a lot of time. Said otherwise, if you want collisions to occur once every 3653 days on average, then you need a hash function with an output of about 35 bits, because *2<sup>35</sup>* is roughly equal to *3653·10<sup>7</sup>*. More bits lower collision rate, of course.

---

All of the above assumes that you are fighting against *random* collisions. If some evil attacker tries to *force* collisions to happen, and can choose the contents of some blocks, then you need the hash function to be collision resistant up to the computational power that the attacker could muster; in that case, use a hash function with an output of at least 160 bits, corresponding to a theoretical resistance of *2<sup>80</sup>* (the traditional limit of attacker's power). Note that some theoretical weaknesses have been found in SHA-1 (the usual 160-bit hash function) so you would prefer using SHA-256, which offers a 256-bit output. If size is constrained, then you may want to truncate the SHA-256 output, but don't reduce it below 160 bits.

An interesting point is that when fighting an attacker, then how many hashes *you* compute is no longer important; what matters is how many the attacker may be able to compute, and he may compute billions per second, way more than your millions per day.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks! We aren't worried about any attack as the files are trusted. We need some headroom because no hash is truly random I guess, but it sounds like 40 bits would be plenty for 1kB blocks from what you are saying.